# Как сделать возврат

Tags: php

Есть текст в файле

```
1;A;B;C;D;F;E
1;A;B;C;D;F;G
```

я  его граблю, создаю массив из данных в тексте, потом изменяю массив, и добавляю опять в файл, но происходит дублирование в текстовом файле как будто удаление `$handle` происходит один раз;

```
1;A;B;C;D;F;E
1;A;B;C;D;F;G;Dobavleno
1;A;B;C;D;F;E;Dobavleno
1;A;B;C;D;F;G;Dobavleno
```

Как прикрутить return или обернуть в функцию?
Желаемый итоговый результат:

```
1;A;B;C;D;F;E;Dobavleno
1;A;B;C;D;F;G;Dobavleno
```

Логика:

```
    $Data=array('E','G'); //массив для поиска в тексте

    foreach ($Data as $key1 => $sec) {
        # code...   
   $file1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   $files = array($file1);

        foreach($files as $file){
        while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        $value[]= explode(';',trim($line)); //создаём массив данных перед удалением содержимого из файла
      }
    }

     $handle = fopen("test.txt","w+"); // Открыть файл, сделать его пустым
    sleep(1);
    fclose($handle);

    foreach ($value as $key => $value1) {
    $fp=$value[$key];

    if($value1[6]==$sec){

    if(isset($value1[7])){

       $fp=array_replace($fp, array('7'=>"Dobavleno")); 
    }else{
      $fp=array_replace($fp, array('7'=>"Dobavleno")); //изменяем массив 
         }
    }

    $toBeSaved = implode(';',$fp); 
    file_put_contents('test.txt', $toBeSaved."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); // записывам из массива построчно в файл

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во первых вы в двух циклах каждый раз открываете файл и записываете строки. И сам `foreach` так же местами надо поменять. Вам надо в каждой строке из файла искать данные из массива для поиска. Значит сначала идем по строчкам, потом в каждой из них ищем нужную букву. Если есть - добавляем, уже после того как поискали все буквы из массива для поиска можно записать новую строчку в файл.

```
$Data = array('E', 'G'); //массив для поиска в тексте

# code...
$file1 = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
$files = array($file1);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        $value[] = explode(';', trim($line)); //создаём массив данных перед удалением содержимого из файла
    }
}
$handle = fopen('test.txt', 'w+'); // Открыть файл, сделать его пустым
sleep(1);
fclose($handle);

foreach ($value as $key => $value1) {
    $fp = $value[$key];
    foreach ($Data as $key1 => $sec) {
        if ($value1[6] === $sec) {

            if (isset($value1[7])) {
                $fp[7] = 'Dobavleno';
            } else {
                $fp[7] = 'Dobavleno'; //изменяем массив
            }
        }
    }

    $toBeSaved = implode(';', $fp);
    file_put_contents('test.txt', $toBeSaved . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); // записывам из массива построчно в файл
}
```

Comment: надж заработало)

Answer (score 2):

какой-то у вас сложный, и местами нелогичный код (одинаковые ветки if-else). Зачем это построчное чтение, если вы все равно весь файл в память загружаете?

```
$haystack = ['E', 'G'];
$data = file("test.txt");

foreach($data as &$l){
    $tmp = explode(';', $l);
    if(in_array($tmp[6], $haystack)) continue;
    $l = trim($l) . ";append\r\n";
}    

file_put_contents("test.txt", implode('', $data));
```

Comment: не одинак,  а перезапись 7 позиции

Comment: @Bloom у вас там две абсолютно идентичных строки кода.

Comment: можно лог прикрутить заменено или добавлено

Comment: @Bloom это вопрос?

Comment: посмотри код на 11 строчку ругается

Comment: в приведенном фрагменте 10 строчек. но я их писал прямо тут, может на что-то и ругается.

Comment: с implode ' ' ';' не работает

Comment: @Bloom `$data` потому что вместо `$l` там должно быть вторым аргументом

Comment: ок.............

Comment: как пропускать добавление значения в массив, допустим если несколько вхождений(строк одинаковых) а добавить только в первое, после этого при следующем проверять  [7] ключ на isset и искать пустой и потом уже туда записывать, как туда прерывание чтоли загнать, делается это для того чтобы одно и тоже в одинаковые строки не пихал, а попорядку

Comment: @Bloom измененные строки складывайте в доп.массив в виде ключей. а потом проверяйте наличие этого ключа в массиве

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DnJctaGz помоги так сделать

Comment: @Bloom если у вас новый вопрос дак задайте его отдельно. сюда он кажется не особо уже вписывается.